# Using secrets in GItHub workflows for private repositories

Tags: github, environment-variables

I'm trying to use the GitHub workflows with the secrets. My setup is:

- Free plan
- Private org
- Private repo
- Secret in the org scope

[image]

The problem is that the secret evaluates into an empty string when I use it like this:

```
echo ${{ secrets.CI_TOKEN }}
```

What's interesting is that it seems like the workflow code itself is perfectly legit because it starts evaluating the secret into `***` when I override it in the repo scope.

[image]

Then I've noticed a possible cause of that problem. The org secrets UI is kind of contradictory. First it says that I can not use secrets for private repos on a free plan but then I can choose the third option and choose that private repos manually.

[image]

[image]

So I wonder whether the free plan actually supports secrets in private repos of private orgs when you select repos manually or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I accidentally found some information on the repo secrets page:

[image]

And it turns out that selecting private repos manually for the org secret is just a broken and misleading UI. You can choose those private repos but it's not gonna work.

I think this UI should be reworked to exclude private repos from that list.

Answer (score 1):

> So I wonder are secrets supposed to work when you choose them manually or not?

For private repos, selecting them explicitely is needed.

The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow) also mentions:

> With the exception of `GITHUB_TOKEN`, secrets are not passed to the runner when a workflow is triggered from a forked repository.

Test them with:

```sh
steps:
  - shell: bash
    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    run: |
      example-command "$SUPER_SECRET"
```

Comment: Can you confirm this works for you on a **free** plan in a **private** repo of a **private** org, when defining the secret **only** for the org and **not** for the repo? It only works for me when I set the secret directly for the repo. When I delete the repo secret and leave only the org one, then the secret stops evaluating.

Comment: @Kolyunya I agree. I cannot test it at the moment, but it does not seem to be working when defined on an org level.